# Why can I print a tuple with 5 elements but not with 6 in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hugs

I tried printing the following tuple

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

which gave me the following error

```
ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
*** Expression : (1,2,3,4,5,6)
*** Of type    : (Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)
```

But if I try it with the following tuple

```
(1,2,3,4,5)
```

everything works like a charm.

My guess is that Haskell only defines `Show` for tuples up to five elements (since a tuple of with 5 elements is apparently another type than a tuple with 6 elements). But somehow I am to stupid to find proof for that.

So my question is:

Why is this so, and how can I print a tuple with 6 elements (since it seems that I cannot put tuples in the head of an `instance` definition)?

**Edit:** I'm using Hugs

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of GHC do you use?

Comment: Same for me can't reproduce it

Comment: I'm using Hugs, edited the question accordingly

Comment: Well, Hugs isn't maintained. It would be a good idea to just switch to GHCi. That said: if you have tuples of size >3, you're probably doing something wrong anyway...

Comment: I fear that Hugs is limited in this aspect. This is no surprise for a software which today is ancient -- it has not been maintained for many years.

Comment: According to [hackage.haskell.org](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:23), `Show`should be implemented for tuples with up to 15 elements. Hugs might be using its own version of the standard prelude.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it reports a bug in an obsolete language implementation.

Comment: @dfeuer Maybe it's useful to have findable questions warning people not to use Hugs anymore. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Include this instance of Show for a 6-tuple

```
-- Tuples   -- for ref, def'n from the Prelude
{-
instance  (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b)  where
  showsPrec p (x,y) = showChar '(' . shows x . showChar ',' .
                                   shows y . showChar ')'


instance  (Read a, Read b) => Read (a,b)  where
    readsPrec p       = readParen False
                        (\r -> [((x,y), w) | ("(",s) <- lex r,
                                             (x,t)   <- reads s,
                                             (",",u) <- lex t,
                                             (y,v)   <- reads u,
                                             (")",w) <- lex v ] )
-}
-- Other tuples have similar Read and Show instances

instance  (Show a, Show b, Show c, Show d, Show e, Show f) 
      => Show (a,b,c,d,e,f)  where
  showsPrec p (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6) = showChar '(' . shows x1 . showChar ',' .
                                   shows x2 . showChar ',' . 
                                   shows x3 . showChar ',' .
                                   shows x4 . showChar ',' .
                                   shows x5 . showChar ',' .
                                   shows x6 . showChar ')'
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use Hugs.

It hasn't been maintained for years, and doesn't support half the stuff that a modern Haskell implementation is supposed to support. (Hugs supports "most of" Haskell '98, which is the previous revision of the language specification.)

You will probably find example code on the Internet that works perfectly with GHC, but fails miserably with Hugs. You will spend ages trying to figure out why your code doesn't work, only to eventually realise "oh, it *does* work — just not with Hugs".

Comment: Hugs is great for getting a painless start with Haskell. I still use it occasionally (on an iPad), despite ~15 years using GHC.   GHC is now so crammed-full of Higher-level typing/kinding that understanding its error messages needs a PhD in abstruse math. Not good to encourage people into Functional Programming. And I think there are introductory CompSci courses that recommend Hugs over GHC

Comment: @AntC: “Hint: the mapping `compiler :: ProgrammingLanguage -> Program` may not be injective...” — yeah, GHC's error messages were never the most beginner-friendly and especially the [FTP](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude) has made it rather worse. But then, times they are a-changing – a lot of the selling point of Haskell is now that it's actually a competitive, full-featured ecosystem that thanks to Stack you can quickly get to run on most platforms. As opposed to the kind of academic, nifty, simple but not-for-production interpreter many Lisps have always stuck with.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: (StackOverflow is not the place to debate this but ...) yes GHC is leading the charge in getting FP recognised for serious industrial-strength programming. I'm worried about how we give a leg-up to newbies to experience the elegance of programming in Haskell. (Esp. coming from an OO paradigm.) What works in Hugs will work in GHC, so it's a good learning platform. IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test on `ghci`

```
Prelude> (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,5 1,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100)

<interactive>:445:1:
    A 100-tuple is too large for GHC
      (max size is 62)
      Workaround: use nested tuples or define a data type
```

However, for printing 15 is the limit

```
Prelude> (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

<interactive>:450:1:
    No instance for (Show
                       (t0,
                        t1,
                        t2,
                        t3,
                        t4,
                        t5,
                        t6,
                        t7,
                        t8,
                        t9,
                        t10,
                        t11,
                        t12,
                        t13,
                        t14,
                        t15))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Show
         (t0,
          t1,
          t2,
          t3,
          t4,
          t5,
          t6,
          t7,
          t8,
          t9,
          t10,
          t11,
          t12,
          t13,
          t14,
          t15))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: Yes GHCi has a limit. Hugs also has a limit, it's just lower. (I agree with the O.P. 5 elements is OK, 6 is not.) What's easy in Hugs is to find where in the Prelude Show instances are defined; copy the code; add your own instances. In GHC not so much.